# Visual Studio 2013 autocomplete turning off randomly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, autocomplete

I know I might sound like a woman complaining about sounds her car is making. But Visual Studio keeps turning off autocomplete.

Sometimes it is for a single file. Sometimes for all files in the current project. Sometimes for every project that I have open.

It just happens randomly, I might go a whole week and it doesn't happen. Or sometimes, like this morning, it turns off 3 times in one hour.

Google seems to offer nothing on this. Any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: just clean the solution and or restart Visual Studio

Comment: I have had similar experiences. I was really impressed with intellisense in Visual Studio 2012, but when I switched to VS 2013 it felt like it was not that good anymore.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes that is what I generally do. Its just disruptive to the workflow to have to do it so often.

Comment: i hear you. i'm currently battlin an issue where every time I right click in visual studio 2013 on windows 8 it freezes for about 5 seconds sometimes 10 to 15.  drives me insane.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes My problem doesn't seem as bad now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also ran into this. I usually have to go to Tools => Options => Text Editor => C# (or whatever language you are using). On that page there is an option for statement completion. Be sure Auto List Members and Parameter information are checked. After I do that it seems to work ok for months. Sometimes, they are checked and I uncheck, then recheck them to solve it.

Comment: I will try this out next time it happens. Expect a response in about 5 minutes.